# R giving "No such file or directory" error

Tags: r, working-directory

I am using the `WDI` and `choropelthr` packages in R Version 3.3.2 and RStudio Version 1.0.44.

The `choroplethr_wdi` command is returning the error when I enter this sample command.

`> choroplethr_wdi(code="NY.GDP.PCAP.CD", year=2012, title="2012 Per Capita Income")`

I get this error message.

`Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  cannot open file '~/R/win-library/3.3/WDI/data/Rdata.rdb': No such file or directory`

I've already checked `getwd()` and the Documents directory is where the R directory is located.

`> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/306/Documents"`

I've also edited permissions on the R directory to make sure permissions were not an obstacle.

If I have the working directory and permissions set correctly, what else would cause this error?

Other packages/commands are working normally, it is just the `choroplethr_wdi` that is giving the errors.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a working directory issue - seems like an internal package directory.

Comment: So does that mean that the package is looking in the Program Files\R directory for these files?  How can I direct the package itself to look in the working directory for the files?

Comment: copy the file, or make a symbolic link (if windows allows)... by the way what is `~` expanded to on windows?

Comment: I thought `~` expanded to the working directory, so it would be `C:\Users\306\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\WDI\data\Rdatat.rdb` but it may be looking in another place.    How do I check the path internal to the package?